# Auto font adjustment in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Speak Python guys! Here's the thing, I was playing with Python and Tkinter until I had an idea to make the font of an input window adjust automatically as new characters are being added, however, the way I did it is not so efficient, and it doesn't turn out perfect. Well, I want to share this test code and ask if you guys know a better way.

Code test...

```
import customtkinter as CTk
from tkinter import *


class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.layout_0 = Tk()

        self.layout_1 = Frame(self.layout_0)
        self.layout_1.grid()

        self.display_back = CTk.CTkEntry(master=self.layout_1, font=('Arial', 50), width=294,
                                         state='disable', corner_radius=0, border_width=0)
        
        self.display_back.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.display_0_var = StringVar()
        self.display_0_var.trace_add('write', self.AutoFontAdjustment)
        
        self.display_0 = CTk.CTkEntry(master=self.layout_1, font=('Arial', 50), 
                                      textvariable=self.display_0_var, width=294, 
                                      justify='right', corner_radius=0, border_width=0, bg_color='black')
        
        self.display_0.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.layout_0.mainloop()


    def AutoFontAdjustment(self, *args):
        TextLength = self.display_0.get()
        MaxCharacters = int(10)
        DefaultFont = int(50)

        if len(TextLength) > MaxCharacters:
            FontDecrease = self.display_0_var.get()
            FontScale = float(1.4)
            FontMin = int(18)

            FontSize = (DefaultFont - len(FontDecrease) * FontScale)
            FontSize = max(FontSize, FontMin)
            self.display_0.configure(font=('Arial', FontSize))

        else:
            self.display_0.configure(font=('Arial', DefaultFont))


MainWindow()
```

I tried several ways, but this was the only one that worked relatively nicely, it's my first turn in Stack.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. Am I right that you are trying to make an Entry, such that if text in it is wider, than Entry's width, text should be decreased to still be fully visible (not partly hidden outside of the borders)?

Comment: @DanyaK Yeah, but the problem is that this way does not make the decrease uniform with the input, and it would be interesting in the same way that it happens in the calculator of windows 10, that is, as the font decreases it seems that the size remains the same.

Comment: I'm sorry for any language issues, because I'm from Brazil and my English is not very good.